# Error in Checkboxlist printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, checkboxlist

Below is my code , im having a hardtime printing it in the desired textbox. Once I select a single checkbox it prints the desired message that I want, but once I chose 2 checkbox it prints two message combined and its an error for me. What I want is when I chose the (A)Checkbox it will display the (A)Message , and when I chose (A) and (B) it will display the (A) and (B) message separately but what happen in my code is when I pick (A) and (B) checkbox it will first display the (A) message , then display the (A) and (B) message combined.

```
protected void PetitionCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < PetitionCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (PetitionCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            message = message + GetDescriptionMessage(PetitionTypeLB.Text.Trim(), "DescriptionMessage", PetitionCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text);
        }//if
    }//for
    DocsMissingTB.Text += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message;
}
```

BTW the GetDescriptionMessage(); method , it gets the description
 message from the database base on the selected petition checkboxlist.

Comment: That's because your event is firing every time you check the _checkbox_.

Comment: but thats what I want , I want to print a message everytime a checkbox in checkboxlist is checked. @RahulSingh

Comment: And that's what exactly is happening in your code: When you check the first checkbox it is printing `A` and when you check the second checkbox it is printing both `A` & `B`.

Comment: So how do I separate both A & B message? @RahulSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, following code is appending your result with previous one :

```
DocsMissingTB.Text += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message;
```

which is long form of

```
DocsMissingTB.Text = DocsMissingTB.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message;
```

So, you do not need to append with previous value and just need to assign fresh value "

```
DocsMissingTB.Text = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message;
```

Comment: Because I want the last message to be intact , what happen is when I used the code that you provided it removes the previous text that the DocsMissingTB have. It happends when I check first the bottom checkbox going to top. But when i check the first checkbox going to the bottom its ok , only it does not have spaces(nextline) like before. @Akash KC

Comment: For that , you can do like this : `message = message + GetDescriptionMessage(PetitionTypeLB.Text.Trim(), "DescriptionMessage", PetitionCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text) + Environment.NewLine`